# jquery getjson dtree

Tags: jquery, getjson

Has anybody try to use dtree combine with $.getJSON ? all pages seems blank the only thing left is the tree, i think its because document.write...any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://rizkyekavianto.blogspot.com/2010/04/dynamic-tree-menujquerydynatreejsonphp.html